# Getting error while running flutter project in simulator in debug mode

Tags: xcode, flutter

Error comes after running flutter run

The Xcode project does not define target "Runner" which is needed by

Flutter

tooling.

Open Xcode to fix the problem:

open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Encountered error while building for device.

Comment: Have you tried solutions on this thread? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22123

Comment: I tried it doesn't work but I fixed it by myself. Thanks

Comment: @SudhansuCronJ how do you fix it? I have the same problem and the easeccy link doesn't work too.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that your app target called "Runner". It seems that flutter tooling relies on this target name.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szH8s.png)